# Laravel 7 Connection refused: You're using the default database name homestead. This database does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer log de usuario estoy teniendo este problema con Laravel 7. Todos los datos de mi bd parecen estar correctos. Uso el puerto 3307 y estoy usando Docker para el proyecto.

Mis .env son:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Para el servicio mysql en docker uso:

```
version: '3'


networks:
  laravel:


services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: e-learning-app_nginx
    ports:
      - "8087:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel


  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: e-learning-app_mysql
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql


  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: e-learning-app_php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9007:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Edit: puse el `docker-compose.yml` completo.

No sé cúal es el problema. Lo raro es que las migraciones me las corre bien y desde cliente para bd puedo conectar todo bien. Ya probé borrando caché de rutas y configuraciones… Estoy usando auth.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO!** aunque no sé si de la manera más "*correcta*".

**Detallo los pasos que me llevaron a la solución:**

1. obtener el *gateway IP* con `docker inspect container_id` (al final del json)
2. agregar en `.env` ésa *IP* como *host* en vez de *127.0.0.1* o *localhost* `DB_HOST=172.18.0.1`
3. agregar a mi `docker-compose.yml` el servicio para *artisan*
4. hacer `docker-compose down` y luego `docker-compose up` (quizá es mejor eliminar los contenedores y los volúmenes para empezar limpio)

**Servicio de *artisan* agregado en** `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: e-learning-app_artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**Mi** `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

**Luego se solucionó el problema** del logueo y pude realizar las migraciones y seeds usando *artisan* desde el contenedor:

`docker-compose run --rm artisan migrate --seed`

**Para conectar desde un cliente externo** como *TablePlus* hago la conexión con los datos:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3307

database: homestead
username: homestead
password: secret
```

**Para acceder a la *aplicación*** sigo utilizando `http://127.0.0.1:8087` o `http://localhost:8087`.

**Todo funcionando bien.**

El docker que estoy utilizando para montar el proyecto lo pueden encontrar en https://github.com/diegoulloao/laravel-docker-startpoint

Answer (score 1):

En mi entorno local también uso Docker Compose para proyectos con Laravel. Prueba a usar el nombre del contenedor como `DB_HOST`. Para más información puedes consultar [aquí](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) la documentación al respecto.

`DB_HOST=mysql`

Comment: El nombre del servicio o el nombre del contenedor? Por favor revisar mi `docker-compose.yml` ya que añadí las propiedades `container_name`

Comment: El nombre del contenedor. En tu caso tienes 3 contenedores: nginx, mysql y php. Si usas la propiedad `container_name` en uno de ellos, puedes darle un nombre personalizado (y como hemos comentado antes, tendrás que actualizar la variable `DB_HOST` si es el host mysql). Más info en https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name

Comment: Sí, estoy usando nombres personalizados. En este caso sería `DB_HOST=e-learning-app_mysql` pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error. Al probar con `DB_HOST=mysql` también.

Comment: En principio así es. Aquí tienes una respuesta más detallada: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55523502/8043571

Answer (score 0):

Si tu base de datos en MySQL se llama homestead no deberias tener problema, si tiene otro nombre debes cambiarlo en la configuración a la base de datos en el archivo .env

El error es porque no existe la base de datos con el nombre "homestead".

Comment: Sí existe! puedo conectar a través de un cliente de base de datos y a través del socket de terminal. Las env están bien.

Answer (score 0):

**Solución 1:**

Hola intenta cambiando tu archivo `.env` para que en lugar de `127.0.0.1` conecte con `localhost` como sigue:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3307
```

Despues desde el contendor ejecuta:

```sh
php artisan migrate
```

**Solucion 2:**

Si eso no funcionó entonces modifica tu archivo `config/database.php` y agrega

```php
'mysql' => [
...
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3307),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
...
],
```

Despues desde el contendor ejecuta:

```sh
php artisan migrate
```

Esta respuesta fue dada en [Stackoverflow en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead) y he tratado de adaptarla para tu caso.

Comment: El problema persiste. Lo que sí, al poner `DB_HOST=localhost` el error que obtengo ahora es: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`, pero al usar `127.0.0.1` el error es: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

Comment: Ahora también descubrí que al usar en `DB_HOST=172.18.0.1` la IP gateway del contenedor (que obtuve con `docker inspect 597ac5e9a7a1`) se arregla el problema y hace el log, el asunto es que ahora las migraciones ya no funcionan, simplemente parece no resolver porque se queda esperando la instrucción sin hacer nada...

Comment: Aún haciendo un `php artisan migrate` desde tu contenedor? Recuerda las migraciones deben hacerse desde el contenedor no desde tu host.

Comment: Sí, ahora que lo arreglé corro las migraciones desde el contenedor.